# PartialView don't render model updated on ajax post call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to do a aplication that request actions on controller and receives back a model with updated information. The steps are simple,

1. Fill some informations on a form.
2. Click on some button to call a action on controller.
3. The action updates the received model and send it back using the PartialView method.

But, the model don't back updated!

Code:

```
    <div id="div-dialog"> // THIS IS A DIALOG JQUERYUI
        <div id="div_toolbar" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"> //THIS IS A TOOLBAR JQUERYUI
            <div style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 420px">
                <button id="btn_novo">Novo</button>
                <button id="btn_gravar">Gravar</button>
                <button id="btn_limpar">Limpar</button>
                <button id="btn_excluir">Excluir</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="partial-render"> //HERE GOES THE PARTIAL VIEW
        @Html.Partial("AvaliationPeriodPartial")
    </div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#div-dialog').dialog({
            height: 'auto',
            width: 600
        });

        $('#btn_novo').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-document"} }).button('enable').click(function () {

            /* ON THIS FUNCTION I SERIALIZE THE INPUTS TO SEND IT TO THE ACTION ON CONTROLLER
               TO UPDATE THE INFORMATION */

            var formData = $('input').serialize();

            $('input[disabled]').each(function () {
                formData = formData + '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val();
            });

            //HERE THE AJAX CALL
            $.post('@Url.Action("teste", "Import")', formData, function (html) {
                $('#partial-render').html(html);
            }, 'html');
    });
</script>
```

Here is the _Layout Page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bem-vindo | @ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the PartialView's code:

```
@model GdaeMVC4.Models.ScreenModels.AvaliationPeriod
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IdAvaliation)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IdAvaliation)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
```

Comment: You need to post the controller action as well.

Comment: have u checked that your ajax call returns with 200 (ok) status code or something else like 500 or 404. you can check it with firebug or fiddler

Comment: return with the status 200...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a break in your javascript code (for example with firebug) and verify that your formdata is indeed sent as you expect.

If formData  seems to be correct, put a break in your Controller Action and verify that the modelbuilder has correctly translated the formdata to the model.

Bonus trivia: The default modelbuilder does not translate "1" to "true" for booleans, perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: The problem is solved! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464407/model-change-in-post-action-not-visible-in-html-textboxfor?rq=1